# Javascript Inheritance, overwriting behavior?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, game-development

This may be a lengthy post. I'm having to learn JS on the fly and could be making simple mistakes.

I'm writing a game in JS/html, and am using [EasyStar](https://easystarjs.com/) to put in some pathfinding behavior for some entities. I'm using inheritance to give the behavior outlined in `Walker4` below to multiple entities, example of one at the bottom:

```
function Walker4(game, img, Ai, lX, lY) {
    this.easyStar = Ai;
    this.dX = 0;
    this.dY = -1;
    this.animation = [];
    this.animation["NE"] = null;
    this.animation["NW"] = null;
    this.animation["SE"] = null;
    this.animation["SW"] = null;
    this.currAnimation = null;
    this.facing = "";
    this.img = img;
    this.isWalking = false;
    this.isFindingPath = false;
    this.destX = null;
    this.destY = null;
    this.path = [];
    this.next = null;
    this.loadCount = 0;
    Entity.call(this, game, lX, lY);
}

Walker4.prototype = new Entity();
Walker4.prototype.constructor = Walker4;

Walker4.prototype.update = function () {

    if (this.isFindingPath) return;
    if (this.isWalking) this.walkPath();

    if (this.destX != null && this.destY != null) {
        this.isFindingPath = true;
        that = this;
        easyStar.findPath(this.x, this.y, this.destX, this.destY, function (path) {
            if (path === null) {
                console.log("No path :(");
            } else {
                console.log("Path! The first Point is " + path[0].x + " " + path[0].y);
                that.path = path;
                that.next = that.path.shift();
                that.isWalking = true;
            }
        });
        this.destX = null;
        this.destY = null;
        this.isFindingPath = false;
        easyStar.calculate();
    }
    Entity.prototype.update.call(this);
}

Walker4.prototype.walkPath = function () {
    if (this.path.length == 0) {
        if (Math.floor(this.x) == this.next.x && Math.floor(this.y) == this.next.y) {
            this.dX = 0;
            this.dY = 0;
        }
        isWalking = false;
        return;
    }
    if (Math.floor(this.x) == this.next.x && Math.floor(this.y) == this.next.y) {
        this.next = this.path.shift();
        this.dX = setDirection(Math.floor(this.x), this.next.x);
        this.dY = setDirection(Math.floor(this.y), this.next.y);
        this.currAnimation = this.animation[setFace(this.dX, this.dY)];
    }

    this.x += this.dX * this.game.clockTick * speed;
    this.y += this.dY * this.game.clockTick * speed;

}




Walker4.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
    pt1 = twodtoisoX(this.x, this.y) + 27 - this.currAnimation.frameWidth / 2;
    pt2 = twodtoisoY(this.x, this.y) + 10 - this.currAnimation.frameHeight / 2;
    ctx.fillRect(pt1, pt2, 5, 5);
    //console.log(pt1, pt2);
    this.currAnimation.drawFrame(this.game.clockTick, ctx, pt1, pt2);
    Entity.prototype.draw.call(this);
}

//Cart Walkers 

function eCartMan(game, img, Ai, lX, lY) {
    Walker4.call(this, game, img, Ai, lX, lY);
    this.animation["NE"] = new Animation(img, 0, 0, 60, 48, 12, aSpeed, 12, true);
    this.animation["NW"] = new Animation(img, 0, 1, 60, 48, 12, aSpeed, 12, true);
    this.animation["SE"] = new Animation(img, 0, 2, 60, 48, 12, aSpeed, 12, true);
    this.animation["SW"] = new Animation(img, 0, 3, 60, 48, 12, aSpeed, 12, true);
    this.currAnimation = this.animation["NE"];
}

eCartMan.prototype = new Walker4();
eCartMan.prototype.constructor = eCartMan;
```

All these entities are added to a list of entities that is updated in a loop each game tick, each having `update` and `draw` called respectively. Easy Star seems to give each entity a path, but then only the most recently added entity will actually follow their given path. What am I missing?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, scoped down the problem. Thanks to @HMR for helping.

Ended up a scope issue on `that = this;`, and that each walker needed its own version of the EasyStar pathfinder. `that` became global, and opened up all instances of the walkers to modifying each other.

Comment: I missed that, should have been `const that = this` You could try editing your code in vs code with [type checking or linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript)